# Two tab menus on one page conflicting with eachother

Tags: javascript

I feel like the solution to this must be obvious but I just cannot figure it out...

I have some very simple vanilla javascript with two tab menus. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to control the two menus independently of each other without creating conflicts. The end goal is to have the two menus initialized and controlled separately from each other.

The codepen is here: https://codepen.io/trevor3999/pen/gOPPoYB

In that codepen, I am selecting elements using shared classes, which clearly is an issue. So I've initialized separates IDs for each tab group, but I just can't figure out how to utilize them...

Any help would be much appreciated – thank you!

**HTML**

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <h2 class="title is-2 has-text-centered is-rift has-margin-top">Featured <span
                        class="has-text-primary">Sensors</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-offset-1">


                <div class="tabs is-medium is-uppercase" id="sensor-tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="is-active" data-tab="1">
                            <a>
                                <span>EO/IR</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="2">
                            <a>
                                <span>Radar</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="3">
                            <a>
                                <span>Other Sensors</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columns is-centered">
            <div class="column is-10">
                <div id="sensor-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                    <menu class="is-active" data-content="1">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
EO/IR
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="2">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Radar
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="3">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Other
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <h2 class="title is-2 has-text-centered is-rift has-margin-top">Featured <span
                        class="has-text-primary">Platforms</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-offset-1">


                <div class="tabs is-medium is-uppercase" id="platform-tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="is-active" data-tab="uas">
                            <a>
                                <span>UAS/RPAS</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="fixed">
                            <a>
                                <span>Fixed Wing</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="rotary">
                            <a>
                                <span>Rotary Wing</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="land">
                            <a>
                                <span>Land</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-tab="naval">
                            <a>
                                <span>Naval</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columns is-centered">
            <div class="column is-10">
                <div id="platform-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                    <menu class="is-active" data-content="uas">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
UAS
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="fixed">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Fixed Wing
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="rotary">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Rotary Wing
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="land">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Land
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                    <menu data-content="naval">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
Naval
                        </div>
                    </menu>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-content menu {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content menu.is-active {
    display: block;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const TABS = [...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li')];
const CONTENT = [...document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content menu')];
const ACTIVE_CLASS = 'is-active';

function initTabs() {
    TABS.forEach((tab) => {
      tab.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let selected = tab.getAttribute('data-tab');
        updateActiveTab(tab);
        updateActiveContent(selected);
      })
    })
}

function updateActiveTab(selected) {
  TABS.forEach((tab) => {
    if (tab && tab.classList.contains(ACTIVE_CLASS)) {
      tab.classList.remove(ACTIVE_CLASS);
    }
  });
  selected.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS);
}

function updateActiveContent(selected) {
  CONTENT.forEach((item) => {
    if (item && item.classList.contains(ACTIVE_CLASS)) {
      item.classList.remove(ACTIVE_CLASS);
    }
    let data = item.getAttribute('data-content');
    if (data === selected) {
      item.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS);
    }
  });
}

initTabs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lazy solution with only a few changes:
https://codepen.io/watofundefined/pen/KKVVROW

```js
console.log("I don't know what kind of code snippet to put here to make the validation happy, sorry!")
```